# C++ ifstream in class error

Tags: c++, ifstream

I've searched around a lot with this question and found a lot of questions that were similar, but I haven't managed to find a solution. I'm declaring a class:

```
class File {

    public:
            string fileName;
            std::ifstream & flinstream;
            Password pass;
            //Next block to look at
            unsigned int nb;
            unsigned int sectorsLeft;
File (string name,string passd);
File ( );
};
```

and a corresponding function:

```
File::File (string name,string passd) {
         fileName =  name;
        const char* cstr =  name.c_str();
         pass =  Password(passd);
         flinstream =  std::ifstream(cstr);
        if(!flinstream.good()) {
            string err =  "The file '";
            err.append(name);
            err.append("' could not be opened!");
            callError(err,3);
        }
    }
```

at compile-time, I get the following errors:

```
 [0] => out.cpp: In constructor ‘File::File(std::string, std::string)’:
    [1] => out.cpp:130:3: error: uninitialized reference member ‘File::flinstream’
    [2] => In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.5/ios:39:0,
    [3] =>                  from /usr/include/c++/4.5/ostream:40,
    [4] =>                  from /usr/include/c++/4.5/iostream:40,
    [5] =>                  from out.cpp:1:
    [6] => /usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/ios_base.h: In member function ‘std::basic_ios<char>& std::basic_ios<char>::operator=(const std::basic_ios<char>&)’:
    [7] => /usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/ios_base.h:788:5: error: ‘std::ios_base& std::ios_base::operator=(const std::ios_base&)’ is private
    [8] => /usr/include/c++/4.5/iosfwd:77:11: error: within this context
    [9] => /usr/include/c++/4.5/iosfwd: In member function ‘std::basic_istream<char>& std::basic_istream<char>::operator=(const std::basic_istream<char>&)’:
    [10] => /usr/include/c++/4.5/iosfwd:83:11: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_ios<char>& std::basic_ios<char>::operator=(const std::basic_ios<char>&)’ first required here
    [11] => /usr/include/c++/4.5/iosfwd: In member function ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>& std::basic_ifstream<char>::operator=(const std::basic_ifstream<char>&)’:
    [12] => /usr/include/c++/4.5/iosfwd:111:11: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_istream<char>& std::basic_istream<char>::operator=(const std::basic_istream<char>&)’ first required here
    [13] => /usr/include/c++/4.5/streambuf: In member function ‘std::basic_filebuf<char>& std::basic_filebuf<char>::operator=(const std::basic_filebuf<char>&)’:
    [14] => /usr/include/c++/4.5/streambuf:781:7: error: ‘std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type& std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>::operator=(const std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>::__streambuf_type = std::basic_streambuf<char>]’ is private
    [15] => /usr/include/c++/4.5/iosfwd:108:11: error: within this context
    [16] => /usr/include/c++/4.5/iosfwd: In member function ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>& std::basic_ifstream<char>::operator=(const std::basic_ifstream<char>&)’:
    [17] => /usr/include/c++/4.5/iosfwd:111:11: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_filebuf<char>& std::basic_filebuf<char>::operator=(const std::basic_filebuf<char>&)’ first required here
    [18] => out.cpp: In constructor ‘File::File(std::string, std::string)’:
    [19] => out.cpp:134:36: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>& std::basic_ifstream<char>::operator=(const std::basic_ifstream<char>&)’ first required here
    [20] => out.cpp: In constructor ‘File::File()’:
    [21] => out.cpp:142:3: error: uninitialized reference member ‘File::flinstream’
    [22] => out.cpp: In member function ‘File& File::operator=(const File&)’:
    [23] => out.cpp:51:12: error: non-static reference member ‘std::ifstream& File::flinstream’, can't use default assignment operator
    [24] => out.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
    [25] => out.cpp:166:57: note: synthesized method ‘File& File::operator=(const File&)’ first required here
)
```

I've gathered that `ifstream` is rather particular with the assignment and all, but I've no idea how to include it in a class. Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: I've tried several permutations of the above class, such as using a normal variable:

```
std::ifstream flinstream;
```

As well as using the `open()` function suggested:

```
flinstream.open(cstr);
```

However, the error remains the same.

Answer (score 3):

For starters, unless you really want a *reference* to an `ifstream`, I would just declare the `ifstream` in your class as

```
std::ifstream flinstream;
```

In C++03 (the previous version of C++), assignment is disabled for stream classes, so the line

```
flinstream =  std::ifstream(cstr);
```

Will not compile.  You can, however, use the `std::ifstream::open` method to do this:

```
flinstream.open(cstr);
/* ... remaining processing ... */
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Precursor- Ah!  I see what's going on.  Because you have an `ifstream` as a field of your class, you cannot copy or assign instances of your class because there is no copy support for the `ifstream`.  Do you really need the `ifstream` as a field?  If so, do you really need to be able to copy your class?

Comment: It's pretty essential. Is there any way I could get my compiler to grudgingly copy it, or should I make a secondary array of ifstreams to supplement the class (so they're not in a class, just in an array of equal size)?

Comment: @Precursor- I would find out where you're making the copy in the first place and see if it's necessary.  If it is, then you should define your own copy constructor and assignment operator so that you can manually reopen the file each time.

Comment: @Precursor: You could use a `std::ifstream *` and use a smart pointer class or just manage the memory allocation yourself. Pointers can be copied with no problem.

Comment: @templatetypedef, I'm just initializing a large global array full of the File class, that's all I've done with it so far.

Comment: @Greg, could you give me an example of a smart pointer class?

Comment: @Precursor: Sure, look up [`shared_ptr`](http://www.google.com/search?q=shared_ptr).

Answer (score 0):

References cannot be left uninitialized. You must initialize all reference members in the initializer list.

flinstream is being initialized in the body of the constructor. By the time the body of the constructor is executing, the value of flinstream must have a legal value. References must always have a legal value.

The initializer list should always be favored over the constructor body.